# '1011' Overlapping (Moore) Sequence Detector in Verilog

Tags: digital-logic, verilog, state-machines, rtl

I'm designing a "1011" overlapping sequence detector, using Moore Model in Verilog .

The FSM that I am  trying to implement is as shown below :-

[image]

Verilog Module :-

```
`timescale 1ns / 1ps

module seq_detector(
input x,clk,reset,
output reg z
);

parameter S0 = 0 , S1 = 1 , S2 = 2 , S3 = 3 , S4 = 4;
reg [1:0] PS,NS ;

    always@(posedge clk or posedge reset)
        begin
            if(reset)
                PS <= S0;   
            else    
                PS <= NS ;
        end             

    always@(PS or x)
        begin 
            
            case(PS)
                S0 : begin 
                            z <= 0 ;
                            NS <= x ? S1 : S0 ;
                            $display(PS);
                        end
                S1 : begin 
                            z <= 0 ;
                            NS <= x ? S1 : S2 ;
                            $display(PS);
                        end
                S2 : begin 
                            z <= 0 ;
                            NS <= x ? S3 : S0 ;
                            $display(PS);
                        end 
                S3 : begin 
                            z <= 0;
                            NS <= x ? S4 : S2 ;
                            $display(PS);
                        end
                S4 : begin 
                            z <= 1; 
                            NS <= x ? S1 : S2 ;
                            $display(PS);
                        end

            endcase
        end
endmodule
```

Testbench :-

```
`timescale 1ns / 1ps

module testbench;
    // Inputs
    reg x;
    reg clk;
    reg reset;
    // Outputs
    wire z;
    // Instantiate the Unit Under Test (UUT)
    seq_detector uut (
        .x(x), 
        .clk(clk), 
        .reset(reset), 
        .z(z)
    );
    
initial
    begin
        clk = 1'b0;
        reset = 1'b1;
        #15 reset = 1'b0;
    end

always #5 clk = ~ clk;  

initial begin
        #12 x = 0;#10 x = 0 ; #10 x = 1 ; #10 x = 0 ;
        #12 x = 1;#10 x = 1 ; #10 x = 0 ; #10 x = 1 ;
        #12 x = 1;#10 x = 0 ; #10 x = 0 ; #10 x = 1 ;
        #12 x = 0;#10 x = 1 ; #10 x = 1 ; #10 x = 0 ;
        #10 $finish;
    end
      
    
endmodule
```

Simulation Output :-
[image]

The issue is that, the output 'z' is staying low always, even when I've applied an input sequence which has three '1011' patterns in it . What's the possible modification that I'd have to do, so as to eliminate this error ?

Comment: This seems to be almost a duplicate of your previous question with exactly the same title. Can you [edit] to explain the difference and modify the title to show the difference. If not this is likely to be closed as a duplicate.

Comment: The state machine(previous was a Mealy design, whereas this is Moore) is different , and the error issue is different . The issue pointed in previous post, has been rectified in this (non-blocking assignment), but still the issue persists.

Comment: The title edit makes it very clear. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**In Moore Machines the output depends only on the current state**. So when you are **changing** your output, (`z` in this case), the sensitivity list should be only the **current state**.

You should add the default case so that  your FSM remains idle when there is no change in the current state.

In your **combinational** block, you should use **blocking statements** to prevent your simulation from running into infinite loops and getting locked up.

Simulate the circuit [here](https://www.edaplayground.com/x/4jNx) on my eda playground:

**Design**:

```
`timescale 1ns / 1ps

module seq_detector(
input x,clk,reset,
output reg z
);

parameter S0 = 0 , S1 = 1 , S2 = 2 , S3 = 3 , S4 = 4;
reg [2:0] PS,NS ;

always @(posedge clk or posedge reset)
    begin
        if(reset)
            PS <= S0;   
        else    
            PS <= NS ; 
    end
always @(PS, x)
begin          
case(PS)
            S0 : begin
                        NS = x ? S1 : S0 ;
                        $display(PS);
                    end
            S1 : begin 
                        NS = x ? S1 : S2 ;
                        $display(PS);
                    end
            S2 : begin 
                        NS = x ? S3 : S0 ;
                        $display(PS);
                    end 
            S3 : begin 
                        NS = x ? S4 : S2 ;
                        $display(PS);
                    end
            S4 : begin 
                        NS = x ? S1 : S2 ;
                        $display(PS);
                    end
            default: NS = S0; 
        endcase
    end
always @(PS)
begin
  case(PS)
    S4: z = 1;
    default: z = 0;
  endcase 
end 
endmodule
```

**Testbench**:

```
 `timescale 1ns / 1ps

 module testbench;
// Inputs
reg x;
reg clk;
reg reset;
// Outputs
wire z;
// Instantiate the Unit Under Test (UUT)
seq_detector uut (
    .x(x), 
    .clk(clk), 
    .reset(reset), 
    .z(z)
);

always #5 clk = ~ clk;  

initial begin
 $dumpfile("dump.vcd");
 $dumpvars(1, testbench);

    fork
    clk = 1'b0;
    reset = 1'b1;
    #15 reset = 1'b0;
    begin 
    #12 x = 0;#10 x = 0 ; #10 x = 1 ; #10 x = 0 ;
    #12 x = 1;#10 x = 1 ; #10 x = 0 ; #10 x = 1 ;
    #12 x = 1;#10 x = 0 ; #10 x = 0 ; #10 x = 1 ;
    #12 x = 0;#10 x = 1 ; #10 x = 1 ; #10 x = 0 ;
    #10 $finish;
    end
    join  
end 
endmodule

`
```

**Waveform:**

https://www.edaplayground.com/w/x/kk

[image]

---

There are totally 32 possibilities to test for this Overlapping FSM because there are 5 states.  **Alternative**: Use a formal property to verify the FSM.

```
property CHK_SEQ_DETECT;
  @(posedge clk) disable iff (reset) x ##1 !x ##1 x[*2] |=> z;
endproperty;


ASSERT_CHK_SEQ_DETECT: assert property (CHK_SEQ_DETECT);
```

Add these lines in the design module, complete setup of formal tool and run it.

## Note:

As mentioned in [Coding And Scripting Techniques For FSM Designs With
Synthesis-Optimized, Glitch-Free Outputs by Clifford Cummings, Sunburst Design, Inc](https://www.sunburst-design.com/papers/CummingsSNUG2000Boston_FSM.pdf),

> The combinational outputs generated by these two coding styles (Example 1 and Example 2)
> suffer two principal disadvantages:
>
> 1. Combinational outputs can glitch between states.
> 2. Combinational outputs consume part of the overall clock cycle that would have been available to the block of logic that is driven by the FSM outputs.

> When module outputs are generated using combinational logic, there is less time for the receiving module to pass signals through inputs and additional combinational logic before they must be clocked.

Hence, coding an overlapping Moore with registered output, in SystemVerilog, and with better signal names:

```
module seq_detector(
   input seq_in, clk, reset,
   output logic detect_out
);

   //one-hot encoding of FSM
   enum logic [4:0] {S0 = 5'b00001, S1 = 5'b00010, S2 = 5'b00100, S3 = 5'b01000, S4 = 5'b10000}  state, next;

   //state registers
   always_ff @(posedge clk or posedge reset)
     if (reset) state <= S0;  
     else       state <= next;

   // Next state assignment logic
   always_comb begin: set_next_state       
     next = state;
     unique case (state)
       S0 : if (seq_in) next = S1; else next = S0;
       S1 : if (seq_in) next = S1; else next = S2;    
       S2 : if (seq_in) next = S3; else next = S0;
       S3 : if (seq_in) next = S4; else next = S2;
       S4 : if (seq_in) next = S1; else next = S2;
     endcase 
     $monitor(state);
   end: set_next_state

   // Registered output logic
   always_ff @(posedge clk, posedge reset)
     if (reset) detect_out <= 1'b0;
     else       detect_out <= (state == S4);

property CHK_SEQ_DETECT;
   @(posedge clk) disable iff (reset) seq_in ##1 !seq_in ##1 seq_in[*2] |=> ##1 detect_out;
endproperty;

ASSERT_CHK_SEQ_DETECT: assert property (CHK_SEQ_DETECT);

endmodule
```

As the input is not directly connected to the output, the FSM is free from being affected by glitches at the input.

Comment: Please don't hand out solutions to questions that are obviously homework. We don't want this site to become a homework answering service. Generally we prefer to give hints that guide the OP to finding their own solutions.

Comment: Also, non-blocking assignments are usually not recommended for combinational logic such as your next-state and output blocks. The `@(*)` event list is also preferred for combinational logic because it is less error-prone.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson, regarding answering homework questions, I don't answer them unless the asker has shown efforts. I follow the guidelines outlined in this answer https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/87/238188

Comment: Are you saying that we should not question the recommendations made by someone with a PhD? Here are recommendations from someone who wrote Verilog code professionally: http://www.sunburst-design.com/papers/CummingsSNUG2000SJ_NBA.pdf

Comment: Later readers of this answer may also want to consider previous discussions on this site: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/91688/difference-between-blocking-and-nonblocking-assignment-verilog or https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/76448/verilog-weird-blocking-nonblocking-problem

Comment: Using `@(*)` would not have changed the behavior in any way...it would still be a Moore FSM. Rather, it would have made the simulation behavior consistent with the hardware behavior, and avoids the occasional error of forgetting to include all necessary signals in the event list. Synthesis tools typically ignore the event list for combinational blocks.

Answer (score 4):

Your state variable is too small.  You have 5 states, but your variable is only 2 bits wide.  It must be at least 3 bits wide.  Change:

```
reg [1:0] PS,NS ;
```

to:

```
reg [2:0] PS,NS ;
```

Now I see `z` go high 3 times.

---

Now that you have unused states (5-7), you should add a `default` to your `case` statement.